# Nativescript-Vue: How to use v-for inside of a ListView correctly

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Using the ListView works, but if I use the v-for in the child component, the view-recycling is not correct, so after scrolling, the v-for does not get re-rendered properly.

My parent component:

```
<ListView for="post in computedPosts">
   <v-template>
     <Post :post="post" ></Post>
   </v-template>
</ListView>
```

My child (post) component:

```
<FlexboxLayout>
   <Label>{{ post.title }}</Label>
   <Label>
     <FormattedString>
       <Span v-for="(span, spanIndex) in post.spans">
        {{ span.content }}
       </Span>
     </FormattedString>
   </Label>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

For example one message says "Hello" and the next "World", both are rendered in a v-for, because a single post can have some styled content. When I scroll down and back up again, so the first post gets re-rendered, it displays "Hello World" instead of the desired "Hello".

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=izWGL9 is a playground to reproduce the issue

Comment: Can you create a playground?

Comment: FormattedString is actually an attribute within Label. I'm not sure how you get to declare it outside label, please refer the docs.

Comment: @Manoj oops, wanted to create a minimal example, but in my code, its there

Comment: Are you having render issues on Android or iOS? In my projects I've always had problems rendering "dynamic" list items on iOS, while working flawlessly on Android

Comment: @TomG I only test with android, maybe should have mentioned that

Comment: @Steven i tried replicating it as clear as possible here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=izWGL9 . just scroll from top to bottom and back up again and you will see that there is more than before.

Comment: @Nais_One I know this problem, It's because sometimes there will be 2 elements or 3 elements being rendered so the other ones stay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this playground is the solution for your issue:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=izWGL9&v=2

What I did is replaced the `FormattedString`:

```
<FlexboxLayout>
    <Label>
         <FormattedString>
           <Span v-for="(span, spanIndex) in post.spans">
            {{ span.content }}
           </Span>
         </FormattedString>
       </Label>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

To this:

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" v-for="(span, spanIndex) in post.contents":key="spanIndex">
        <Label textWrap="true" :text="span" class="content-span"></Label>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, for future readers, this is currently a bug in nativescript-vue 2.2 and a github issue was created for this